# I need to solve this limit without using L'Hospital's rule

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

I need to solve this limit without using L'Hospital's rule.

$$\lim_{x\to 0}⁡(\cos x)^\left(\frac{-4}{x^2}\right)⁡$$

Comment: This looks like a homework problem. Have you tried anything?

Comment: I have solved it for a friend using l'Hospital's rule. Unfortunately, my friend is attending high school and he doesn't know this rule. I don't remember how to solve it without using l'Hospital's rule.That's why I am asking for an advice here.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$$(\cos x)^{-4/x^2}=(1-\sin^2x)^{-2/x^2}=\left(\left(1-{1\over\csc^2x} \right)^{\csc^2x}\right)^{-2\left(\sin x\over x\right)^2}$$

Can you (and/or your friend) take it from there?

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much!